# How to capture the send output and resend the output to a echo statement in expect scripting

Tags: expect, send

I am using expect script and I'm executing it  on my local system .

As part of the script, I have to connect to a remote server and I have to print the output of a command in the echo statement .

Like

send "echo 'the service mysql is [service mysqld status]'\r".

On the remote system, I want the below output to be printed .

the service mysql is running/stopped/started.

Here is the code snipped I was trying with :

`#!/usr/bin/expect -f
    #!/bin/bash
    spawn ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o CheckHostIP=no -o                              StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@remotehost
    expect "password: "
    send "12shroot\r"
    expect "#"
    send "echo 'service status of mysql is $[/sbin/service mysqld status]'\r"
   expect eof`

I am getting the below error :

invalid command name "/sbin/service"
    while executing
"/sbin/service mysqld status"
    invoked from within
"send "echo 'number of blades including ms is $[/sbin/service mysqld status]'\r""

```
(file "/tmp/hudson3843443005004841895.sh" line 7)
```

Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Please help !!!

I tried with expect_out(buffer). But the complete console o/p was part of it .

I w'd like to know if we can execute the command as part of echo on a remote server by using send .

Thanks a million in Advance

Comment: Use `exec` command to know the status of mysql service.

Comment: I require the o/p to be part of echo.
exec "echo 'service status of mysql is $[/sbin/service mysqld status]'\r".
Will this help ?

Comment: `set result [exec /sbin/service mysqld status]` - The variable `result` will hold the result of the above.